# "Listing #" below listings without a caption

Tags: listings, captions

When not specifying a caption for a lstlisting nothing is shown below the listing while "Listing #: mycaption" is displayed as soon as I specify a caption.

However, I'd like "Listing #" to be displayed for all listings; even those without a caption (those with a caption should keep their "Listing #: mycaption" of course).
Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `caption=\relax`; however, then you'll get "Listing #:" with the colon. I don't know how to remove this.

EDIT: OK, here's a nasty hack that removes the colon if the caption is `\relax`. It works with my version of `listings`, but it might not work in future versions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\test@relax{\relax}
\let\save@fnum@lstlisting\fnum@lstlisting
\def\fnum@lstlisting{%
    \save@fnum@lstlisting
    \ifx\lst@caption\test@relax\expandafter\@gobble\fi
    }
\makeatother
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=\relax]
a:=b
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've already got that answer on IRC - with the caption below the listing that looks pretty ugly so it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I agree, it's pretty ugly to have the ":".

Answer (score 1):

My idea is everything else than a nice solution but here you go:

```
\newcommand\emptytitle{\lstlistingname\ \thelstlisting}
\newcommand\nextlst{\addtocounter{lstlisting}{1}}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,title=\emptytitle]
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hallo Welt!\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} /* end main() */
\end{lstlisting}

\nextlst
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,title=\emptytitle]
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hallo Welt!\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} /* end main() */
\end{lstlisting}
```

Btw. `\newcommand\emptytitle{\lstlistingname\ \thelstlisting \nextlst}` does not work because somehow the counter makes +2 jumps.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to pass this title argument

```
title={\lstlistingname\space\thelstlisting}
```

to each listing. This very tedious, but I'm using Lyx, so it's relatively simple to just copy listings arounds.